# Jersey client examples in Neo4j Manual

Tags: java, neo4j, jersey-client

I want to use the Jersey client to connect via REST with a Neo4j database. In the Neo4j manual they have examples of this in Tutorials->Languages->How to use the REST API from Java. I want to create a new node and then use Cypher to add relationships to it. In the Neo4j example (https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/2.2.9/community/server-examples/src/main/java/org/neo4j/examples/server/CreateSimpleGraph.java) they use 'createNode', but the documentation suggests that that is only available using an embedded Neo4j server.

Does calling createNode() work in a RESTful context?

Comment: If this question is too clueless or too dumb, I apologize. But I really don't know the answer. Would someone at least point me to the manual sections where I might find the answer? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example that you reference, the `createNode` function as defined [here](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/2.2.9/community/server-examples/src/main/java/org/neo4j/examples/server/CreateSimpleGraph.java#L142-164) is simply making an HTTP POST request to `http://localhost:7474/db/data/node` which will create a new node:

```
private static URI createNode()
{
    final String nodeEntryPointUri = SERVER_ROOT_URI + "node";
    // http://localhost:7474/db/data/node

    WebResource resource = Client.create()
            .resource( nodeEntryPointUri );
    // POST {} to the node entry point URI
    ClientResponse response = resource.accept( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
            .type( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
            .entity( "{}" )
            .post( ClientResponse.class );

    final URI location = response.getLocation();
    System.out.println( String.format(
            "POST to [%s], status code [%d], location header [%s]",
            nodeEntryPointUri, response.getStatus(), location.toString() ) );
    response.close();

    return location;
}
```

This function is defined in the sample code and is completely different than the [`createNode` function that is part of the embedded Java API](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService.html#createNode()).

If you are interested in working with the new Neo4j 3.0 version (currently RC) there is a new Java driver that supports Cypher [here](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-java-driver).

Comment: Thank you William. Thanks for clarifying.